# How to check available dates in laravel and mongo

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am developing a hotel booking availability check using laravel and mongodb. I am confused to write query to find available dates. I tried a method but it is like `between and`. I am not sure query is correct or not.

I have included laravel raw query and mongo query in this question. Both are same.

**Why query is not correct?**

Because, Guest checking on `2017-09-02` and checkout on `2017-09-05`. Currently I am fetching data like `2017-09-02 >= checkin_from && 2017-09-05 <= checkin_from`. If `2017-09-02` is the `checkin_from` date then, this is correct. But if `checkin_from` is `2017-08-25` and `reserve_to` is `2017-09-06`. Here dates `2017-09-02 to 2017-09-05` includes. In this case how will we check?

Is this possible with query?

Or

Array 1: Fetch all the bookings and store in an array.

Array 2: Then prepare date (checkin and checkout date from frontend) using DatePeriod and DateInterval and store in an array. Then check matching array(1 & 2).

Which method do I follow?

**Query Currently I am using**

```
$bookings                = Booking::raw(function ($collection) use ($dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
                    return $collection->aggregate([
                        [
                            '$match' => [
                                'cabinname' => 'test',
                                'checkin_from' => ['$gte' => $dateBegin, '$lte' => $dateEnd],
                                'is_delete' => 0,
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            '$project' => [
                                'beds' => 1,
                                'dormitory' => 1,
                                'sleeps' => 1,
                                'status' => 1,
                                'has status' => [
                                    '$in' => ['status', ['1', '4', '5', '7']]
                                ]
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]);
                });
```

**Mongo Query**

```
db.booking.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "cabinname" : 'Test',
      "checkin_from" : {$gte :[ new Date ('2017-09-01') ], $lte : [ new Date ('2017-09-03') ] },
      "is_delete" : 0,
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "beds" : 1,
      "cabinname":1, 
      "checkin_from":1, 
      "reserve_to":1,
      "has status" : {
        $in: [ "status", ['1', '4', '5', '7'] ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Data from database**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5888fbd5d2ae672245fb5f79"), "cabinname" : "Test", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-08-29T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-09-03T22:00:00Z"), "beds" : "8" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58a4812bd2ae67066eeaea41"), "cabinname" : "Test", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-09-01T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-09-05T22:00:00Z"), "beds" : "18" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58bac8a5d2ae67951845edaf"), "cabinname" : "Test", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-09-01T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-09-02T22:00:00Z"), "beds" : "0" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58d03541d2ae671c668b4568"), "cabinname" : "Test", "checkin_from" : ISODate("2017-09-02T22:00:00Z"), "reserve_to" : ISODate("2017-09-04T22:00:00Z"), "beds" : "14" }
```

Comment: So the problem is you are unable to query to determine intersection between two date(check in and check out date) ranges ? Am I right ? or something else please explain :D

Comment: @SagarGautam, Yes correct.

Comment: I've done similar problem with some array operation but with queries it might be complex as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query is not working because of wrong conditions. I have updated the conditions now I am getting exact results.

`{checkin_from:{$lte: new Date ('2017-09-02')}, reserve_to:{$gt: new Date ('2017-09-02')}}`

```
$bookings                = Booking::raw(function ($collection) use ($dateBegin, $dateEnd) {
                    return $collection->aggregate([
                        [
                            '$match' => [
                                'cabinname' => 'test',
                                'checkin_from' => ['$lte' => $dateBegin],
                                'reserve_to' => ['$gt' => $dateBegin],
                                'is_delete' => 0,
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            '$project' => [
                                'beds' => 1,
                                'dormitory' => 1,
                                'sleeps' => 1,
                                'status' => 1,
                                'has status' => [
                                    '$in' => ['status', ['1', '4', '5', '7']]
                                ]
                            ],
                        ]
                    ]);
                });
```